# Wpf Listview Disable Selected Item Color

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have a listview:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem  Height="40">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2 0">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AddCall" Width="22" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Listbox 1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Margin="12 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>

    <ListViewItem Height="40">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2 0">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="RemoveCircle" Width="22" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Listbox 2" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Margin="12 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

The listview looks like the first picture when the program starts.

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VauS5.png)

When I click the one of the items, it changes as below.

[Selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y37XM.png)

I want to remove the gray background in the picture. So I don't want the background to change when I click on the item. I'm using material design xaml. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

do you want to have these items selectable in the first place?

If not, I would suggest using the ItemsControl instead of the ListView. ItemsControl doesn't have selection, so there would be no highlight coloring and there are plenty of ways to make the ItemsControl items clickable (i.e. using Buttons, MouseClick triggers, etc.).

Hope this helps,
Michal.